# python code similar to Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment power shell command

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am writing a python code where in i need to fetch all the deployments within a resource group and check for its provisioning status. I am using Resource management client which will fetch all the resources within the resource group but not the deployments details..

we have a power shell command for that `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`
But I want this work to be done using python

Please help me to  resolve this.

```
 Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "RGDemo"

DeploymentName          : Microsoft.VirtualNetwork-20190517162503
ResourceGroupName       : RGDemo
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 17-05-2019 10:55:36
Mode                    : Incremental
```

Need python class which will perform similar function

Comment: Any update with the answer below? You need to give the response if the answer works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

def get_credentials():
    subscription_id = os.environ['AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID']
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
        secret=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        tenant=os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
    )
    return credentials, subscription_id

credentials, subscription_id = get_credentials()
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
deployments = resource_client.deployments.list_by_resource_group('RGDemo')

for deploy in deployments:
    print(deploy.name)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.operations.deploymentsoperations?view=azure-python#list-by-resource-group-resource-group-name--filter-none--top-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-